# SD card root access

Tags: root-access, sd-card, storage, command-line

Hey I just wanted to ask how it is possible to access my sdcard data with command lines on a rooted phone ? I tried to `ls` in `/sdcard`, also in `/mnt/sdcard/` but my files are never displayed, yet a simple file manager shows those files exist.

Comment: Provide some more details like phone manufacturer and os version ...

Comment: Or you can also find correct path by using the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23737335/3303075

Comment: It is a Logicom Lement400 android 4.4.2. I don't understand, from the link are you supposed to compile those code ? I need to access these files from sh

Comment: I have an rpm file that I need to install. I could just copy it somewhere else with file manager but I don't want to leave too many understanding behind.

Comment: What tool are you using to access the commandline? A terminal app, or `adb shell`? I'm using the latter normally, and contents are always shown. // Btw: You cannot install RPM files on Android :)

Comment: Then try them one by one you can get result from one of the paths.

Comment: Izzy: if the file is build for arm why shouldn't it install ? I'm using a terminal emulator, adb is when you command from your computer ? Thanks I will keep trying

Comment: RPMs are for a specific type of package manager for Linux systems... Android is not Linux although it is based on it, and does not have an rpm package manager. Android uses APK packages and runs then in a sandbox java VM, standard Linux applications even if for the correct architecture do not work.

Comment: If so why did I get a rpm binary from a busybox apk ? My intend was to install tripwire

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to mount the phone onto the filesystem of a Linux computer over a USB connection. You don't even need to root the phone.

`$ mkdir mnt`

`$ jmtpfs mnt`

`$ cd mnt/Card`